# Override Yii2 andWhere() conditions

Tags: yii2

All through my yii2 application, I want to turn queries like:

```
Post::find()->andWhere(['id'=>$id])->one();
```

into

```
Post::find()->andWhere(['id'=>'uuid_to_bin('.$id.')'])->one();
```

Because this code is everywhere, I don't want to have to go through and manually change every single query. So what I thought it would be easier is to just override one of yii2's base classes similar to this approach here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-overview.html#customizing-helper-classes and check if we have the `id` as a column condition, we'll just do some converting of the condition.

Which class should I override so that whenever `andWhere()` and `orWhere()` and `where()`, etc is called, I can easily update and convert the query condition?

Comment: this thing can not be achieved via helpers you have to override the yii\db\Query class for this

Comment: Yes true, but assuming it would be the same approach of overriding a core class and would yii\dbQuery be the right class?

Comment: It might be same but helpers will behave different. In case of helper you have to make manual changes everywhere

Comment: I added `Yii::$container->set('yii\db\ActiveQuery', 'common\components\ActiveQuery');` to `bootstrap.php` and my new ActiveQuery extending yii's ActiveQuery. This works! However, it doesn't work for `yii\db\Query`... :\

Comment: `yii\db\Query` is separate class, you have to override it aswell by `dependency injection`, like you did for `yii\db\ActiveQuery`

Comment: Yes, I understand - it works perfectly for `ActiveQuery` but `Query` just won't work with the exact same overriding of the dependency.

Answer (score -1):

if your model generated by gii and `Generate ActiveQuery` is checked.

you can find this code in your generated query class

```
/*public function active()
{
    return $this->andWhere('[[status]]=1');
}*/
```

call the function like this

```
Post::find()->active()->one()
```

good luck